# Criando bat em tempo de execução e processo no delphi

Tags: delphi, batch, delphi-xe6, windows-7

Tenho duas funções que criam um arquivo `bat` e o executa, mas simplesmente não estou conseguindo criar o processo (`CreateProcess` retorna `False`) e não consigo identificar o erro.

Eu uso o Windows 7, de 64 bits. Devo mudar algum parâmetro na função `WinExecAndWait32`? Como debugar o `CreateProcess`?

Obs.: A mesma função funcionava no XE5.

Essa é a função que cria o arquivo `bat`, o executa, e depois o deleta:

```pascal
function AddDeleteServico(comando: string): boolean;
var
   txt: TextFile;
   dir: string;
   ret: boolean;
begin
  ret:=False;
  try
     dir:=ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
     AssignFile(txt, dir + 'meu.bat');
     Rewrite(txt);
     Write(txt,comando);

     CloseFile(txt);
     if WinExecAndWait32(dir + 'meu.bat',dir,SW_ShowNormal) = 0 then
         ret:=True;
     DeleteFile(PChar(dir + 'meu.bat'));
  finally
     AddDeleteServico:=ret;
  end;
end;
```

Essa é a função que cria o processo:

**EDIÇÃO:**Após a ajuda dos colegas ela a função ficou assim:

```pascal
 function WinExecAndWait32(ExeName: string; CmdLineArgs: string = '';
  ShowWindow: boolean = True; WaitForFinish: boolean = False): integer;
var
  StartInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcInfo: TProcessInformation;
begin

  FillChar(StartInfo,SizeOf(TStartupInfo),#0);
  FillChar(ProcInfo,SizeOf(TProcessInformation),#0);
  StartInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);

  if not(ShowWindow) then begin
    StartInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    StartInfo.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
  end;

  CreateProcess(nil,PChar(ExeName + ' ' + CmdLineArgs),nil,nil,False,
    CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP + NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,nil,nil,StartInfo,
    ProcInfo);

  Result := ProcInfo.dwProcessId;

  if WaitForFinish then begin
    WaitForSingleObject(ProcInfo.hProcess,Infinite);
  end;

  CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hProcess);
  CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hThread);
end;
```

Comment: Ao invés de simplesmente retornar -1, chame a função RaiseLastOSError

Comment: Você está deixando vazar os handles do processo e da thread que você criou também, você deveria limpá-los: `CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);``CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);`

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um arquivo `bat` não é um executável. Tal qual o `sh`, ele é apenas um arquivo de texto, que precisa ser interpretado e aí sim seus comandos são executados pelo interpretador.

Porém, Linux, o Windows não sabe escolher um interpretador para executá-lo diretamente (pelo menos não as funções tradicionais de criação de processo) e não há um mecanismo para descobrir qual interpretador utilizar para executar o programa (esta é a função da linha `#!/bin/sh` nos arquivos `sh` e em outros).

Portanto, no Windows, é necessário invocar o interpretador para que ele execute o `bat`. No Linux, este programa seria o `bash` (ou equivalente). No Windows, é o `cmd.exe`.

Assim, seu comando deve executar o `cmd` e passar por parâmetro o `bat` a ser executado. Modifiquei sua função original para fazer isto. Não a testei, pois não tenho o Delphi instalado (nem o Lazarus), mas o conceito é este. Adicionei também os comandos para fechar os handles criados, conforme comentários na pergunta.

```
function WinExecBatAndWait(FileName: String; WorkDir: String; Visibility: integer): integer;
var
   zAppName: PChar;
   zCurDir: PChar;
   StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
   ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation;
begin
  // necessário executar o cmd.exe!
  FileName:= GetEnvironmentVariable('COMSPEC') + ' /C ' + FileName;
  zAppName:= PChar(FileName);
  zCurDir:= PChar(WorkDir);
  FillChar(StartupInfo,Sizeof(StartupInfo),#0);
  StartupInfo.cb:=Sizeof(StartupInfo);
  StartupInfo.dwFlags:=STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  StartupInfo.wShowWindow:=Visibility;

  if not CreateProcess(nil,zAppName,nil,nil,False,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,nil,zCurDir,StartupInfo,ProcessInfo) then
     Result:=-1
  else
  begin
     WaitforSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);
     GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess,DWORD(Result));
     CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);``CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
  end;
end;
```

Não se esqueça que pode ser necessário adicionar `"` nos argumentos caso eles tenham espaços!

**"Mas quando clicko duas vezes no arquivo no meu desktop ele executa!"**

O que acontece, é que o shell (executado pela primeira instância do aplicativo `explorer.exe` no usuário) sabe identificar qual interpretador utilizar para executar este arquivo. E como ele sabe isso? A partir de uma simples associação de arquivo.

**"Mas o shell não usa `CreateProcess` quando eu clicko duas vezes no arquivo (ou `bat`)? Por que com ele funciona e comigo não?"**

Não. O shell utiliza a API `ShellExec`, que antes de executar o `CreateProcess` varre o registro para identificar como "executar" o arquivo, ou qual programa chamar para manipular o arquivo, e então monta a linha de comando apropriada.

Comment: +1 pela explicação.Muito Obrigado, quando chegar numa maquina com o Delphi eu vou testar.